# Get error with Puppet running on MIPS: Could not create resources for managing Puppet's files and directories in sections

Tags: ruby, mips, puppet

I try to port puppet running on MIPS platform, but get some errors. The version of the related software is here:
Ruby: 1.8.7 ( cross-compile with openssl and openldap ),
facter: 1.6.12,
puppet: 2.7.19

When I execute the command: "puppet agent -t --trace --debug", I get the error message as follows, does anyone know how to fix these? Thanks a lot.

```
> puppet agent -t --trace --debug
warning: iconv doesn't seem to support UTF-8/UTF-16 conversions
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roledel does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUseradd: file usermod does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: true value when expecting false
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roledel does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUseradd: file usermod does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: true value when expecting false
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/type/user.rb:355:in `exists?'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:451:in `service_user_available?'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings/file_setting.rb:45:in `use_service_user?'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings/file_setting.rb:40:in `owner'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings/file_setting.rb:109:in `to_resource'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:555:in `to_catalog'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:553:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:553:in `to_catalog'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:612:in `use'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/sync.rb:230:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:606:in `use'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application/agent.rb:459:in `setup'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:307:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:416:in `hook'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:307:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:407:in `exit_on_fail'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:307:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:69:in `execute'
/usr/bin/puppet:4
err: Could not create resources for managing Puppet's files and directories in sections [:main, :agent, :ssl]: undefined method `exists?' for nil:NilClass
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roledel does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUseradd: file usermod does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: true value when expecting false
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roledel does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUseradd: file usermod does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: true value when expecting false
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/type/user.rb:355:in `exists?'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:451:in `service_user_available?'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings/file_setting.rb:45:in `use_service_user?'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings/file_setting.rb:40:in `owner'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings/file_setting.rb:109:in `to_resource'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:555:in `to_catalog'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:553:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:553:in `to_catalog'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:612:in `use'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/sync.rb:230:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/settings.rb:606:in `use'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/ssl_file.rb:50:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:321:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:321:in `make_terminus'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:130:in `terminus'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:309:in `prepare'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:188:in `find'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/ssl/host.rb:138:in `key'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/ssl/host.rb:195:in `certificate'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/ssl/host.rb:291:in `wait_for_cert'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application/agent.rb:407:in `setup_host'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application/agent.rb:425:in `setup_agent'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application/agent.rb:484:in `setup'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:307:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:416:in `hook'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:307:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:407:in `exit_on_fail'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:307:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:69:in `execute'
/usr/bin/puppet:4
err: Could not create resources for managing Puppet's files and directories in sections [:main, :ssl]: undefined method `exists?' for nil:NilClass
info: Creating a new SSL key for mymachine.localdomain
Floating point exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet tries to create user and groups (possible because [mkusers](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#mkusers) option).

But it couldn't do that because neither of user's provider work (because of lack of executable).

You can see it in the listing below.

```
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roledel does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUseradd: file usermod does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: true value when expecting false
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roledel does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUseradd: file usermod does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: true value when expecting false
```

So you should provide at least one of executable needed for user provider.